# What is the algebraic closure of $K(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field, and $x$ an element transcendental over $K$.

We know that $K(x)$ is not algebraically closed, in fact it is enough to consider the polynomial $t^2 - x$ ([Algebraic closure of $K(X)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1993393)).

Is there a way to explicitly describe $\overline{K(x)}$?

Comment: As soon as you start looking at $K(x)$, you’re dealing with geometry. You are asking, among many other things, what all the algebraic curves over $K$ are.

Comment: On the other hand, the field of Puiseux series is the algebraic closure of $k((x))$ if $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0.

Comment: For $K=\Bbb C$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59826